# error: conversion from ‘Mstream’ to non-scalar type ‘std::string {aka std::basic_string<char>}’ requested

Tags: c++, c++11

Could you please help me to resolve the error in the below code.

```
class Mstream{
     unsigned int len;
     char *str;
};

int main(){
   Mstream m1;
   std::string str=m1;// i see error at this statement
}
```

error:

> conversion from ‘Mstream’ to non-scalar type ‘std::string {aka std::basic_string<char>}’ requested

Comment: `std::string str=m1.str` or `std::string str(m1.str, m1.len);`?

Comment: uh `string`is not the same type as `Mstream`? I suppose you're trying to access `str`?

Answer (score 0):

`std::string` does not have a constructor or `operator=` that takes an `Mstream` as input.  It does, however, have a constructor that takes a `char*` and size as input:

```
int main(){
    Mstream m1;
    std::string str(m1.str, m1.len);
}
```

Alternatively, you can add a `std::string` conversion operator to `Mstream`, then you can assign an `Mstream` to a `std::string`:

```
class Mstream{
    unsigned int len;
    char *str;
    operator std::string() const { return std::string(str, len); }
};

int main(){
    Mstream m1;
    std::string str = m1;
}
```

Either way, do make sure the `Mstream` is properly initialized with a valid `char*` pointer and length value *before* attempting to do the conversion to `std::string`.